# C# Variable Expression Func Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reflection, lambda, expression

I'm writing a dynamic model binder that binds functions to api calls.

This is my test controller with 2 functions. They have different functions with **different parameter types**.

```
public class MyTestController : System.Web.Mvc.Controller {

    public ActionResult MyFunction() {
        // Do awesome stuff
        return result;
    }

    public ActionResult MyOtherFunction(int i) {
        // Do other awesome stuff
        return result;
    }
}
```

With this model binder I want to to be able to select the specific functions and create my api call name.

```
public static class ModelBinder {
    public static string GetApiCall<T>( Expression<Func<T, Func<ActionResult>>> expression ) {
        var unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression.Body;
        var methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
        var methodInfoExpression = (ConstantExpression)methodCallExpression.Arguments.Last();
        var methodInfo = (MemberInfo)methodInfoExpression.Value;

        var controllerName = typeof( T ).Name.Replace( "Controller", "" );
        var methodName = methodInfo.Name;

        var myApiCallName = string.Format( "{0}_{1}", controllerName, methodName ).ToLower();
        return myApiCallName;
    }
}
```

Using the ModelBinder works with functions in the controller class without parameters. But not with the parameterized function.

```
var apiCallName1 = ModelBinder.GetApiCall<MyTestController>( x => x.MyFunction );
var apiCallName2 = ModelBinder.GetApiCall<MyTestController>( x => x.MyOtherFunction ); // Compiler Says no!
```

It's not possible to compile because the function definition does not match. In this case I would need to define another **GetApiCall** Method with another parameter type of **Expression>>**.

**So here's the actual question:**

Is there any type in C# that accepts all kinds of delegate types, but it bound to a specific return type? So only functions that return a results of type of ActionResult.

```
public static string GetApiCall<T>( Expression<Func<T, MagicDelegateTypeThatTakesAllFunctionsWithAllParameterTypes>> expression ) {
    // do awesome stuff
}
```

**Edit**

Thank you @LeBaptiste for the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225302/get-the-name-of-a-method-using-an-expression). It is Possible the make the function call with the **Delegate** data type.

```
public static string GetApiCall<T>( Expression<Func<T, Delegate>> expression ) {
    // do awesome stuff
}

// Calling the method
ModelBinder.GetApiCall<MyTestController>( x => new Func<int, ActionResult>( x.MyOtherFunction ) );
```

**Is there any way to get some sort of auto boxing this call, so I dont have to write this Func wrapper all the time?**

Comment: do you need to include the param for MyOtherFunction?  `x => x.MyOtherFunction(i)`

Comment: No I just need the function name

Comment: This looks like to answer your need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225302/get-the-name-of-a-method-using-an-expression

Comment: Why do you need to care about return type in your parameter? You don't need to do `typeof(T)` when you can just get rid of the generic and do something like `expression.Body.Type`.

Comment: I don't think what you originally were trying to do is possible. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798434/can-you-declare-a-variable-length-generics-type-declaration). This is the same reason in the .NET library you see separate defintions for `Func<T>`, `Func<T, TResult>`, `Func<T1, T2, TResult>`, etc...